# How to attach actionListener for events in Richfaces 4

Tags: jsf, richfaces, actionlistener, ajax4jsf

I have the follwoing code from Richfaces 3.3

```
<h:inputText id="transamount" value="#{myBean.amount}">
    <a4j:support event="onkeyup" ajaxSingle="true" actionListener="#{myBean.validTransAmt}" requestDelay="200" ignoreDupResponses="true" reRender="main,submitButton" />
</h:inputText>
```

I need to upgrade it to Richfaces 4 and am unsure how to attach the **actionListener** now as it's not supported under the **a4j:ajax** component which replaces a4j:support.

This is what I have so far.

```
<h:inputText id="transamount" value="#{myBean.amount}">
    <a4j:ajax event="onkeyup" reRender="main,submitButton" />
</h:inputText>
```

Could someone explain how to attach an actionListener here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just requires the use of the 'listener' attribute instead:

```
<h:inputText id="transamount" value="#{myBean.amount}">
    <a4j:ajax event="onkeyup" listener="#{myBean.validTransAmt}" reRender="main,submitButton" />
</h:inputText>
```

Answer (score 1):

richfaces 4.0 uses a different syntax as 3.x
in your case: 
onkeyop = keyup
reRender = render

don't use a comma to separate values in the 'render' attribute.

try:

```
<h:inputText id="transamount" value="#{myBean.amount}">
    <a4j:ajax event="keyup" listener="#{myBean.validTransAmt}" render="main submitButton" />
</h:inputText>
```